# How to aggregate specific mongodb 1d array element

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I have a bunch of collection documents similar to this

```
{
    eReal : [10000,4000,1]
    timestamp : 1465877805,
    ...other items ect.
}
```

And I want to aggregate by values in the eReal 1d array such as this projection

```
var project = {

        "$project":{
            "_id": 0,

            "prod": "$eReal.1",
            "cons": "$eReal.0",

        }
    };


    var group =  { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "prod" : "$prod"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }};
```

But I cannot seem to be able to access these eReal values, I have tried unwinding eReal however I cannot seem to be able to access the unwind.

Using Meteor with aggregation:meteorhacks

Comment: What's your mongodb version? Use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) operator can read the element at the specified array index in `$project` expression, but it's new in version 3.2.

Comment: Dang, meteor still isn't using 3.2 rather 2.6.10. There are so many aggregation functions available with 3.2 too :/